# Using ubuntu18.04 in raspberrypi4b 1G to 2G cannot boot normally

Tags: raspberrypi

I bought a pi4 1G in 2020 and installed ubuntu18.04 and ROS, but I need to upgrade to 4G due to memory requirements, and I bought it last month.
But I put the 1G Raspberry Pi memory card into the 4G Raspberry Pi, and found that a rainbow appeared when I turned it on.
Because there are a lot of files installed in it, how do I update it so that my memory card can still be used?
#4G Raspberry Pi is available, cross-tested.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded all the .dat and .elf from here and copied to boot and it works fine now.
https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware ... aster/boot

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but I think that upon installation time, Ubuntu will detect the hardware environment, and set up configurations (including drivers to be used) according to that hardware environment.

If you afterwards put the card (the entire installed OS) into another device, the configs that are written on your card will no longer match the hardware components.

I could imagine you could get a working Ubuntu 18.04 on your new hardware by running the installer for the OS anew on the new device. (This assumes that the new Pi contains only such hardware that can be managed through drivers that are available in the 18.04 ecosystem. If that's not the case, you would need to try a more recent version, like 20.04).

This doesn't solve however your issue with "a lot of files installed in it". As a most reliable measure, you would need to stash your files temporarily on e.g. an additional USB stick.